# How to find bounds in derivation of Stirling's Formula

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, probability

I'm reading a very nice note by Terry Tao on Stirling's Formula (https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/01/02/254a-notes-0a-stirlings-formula/).

At one point in the derivation he states:
$$ \text{“ } n \log\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right) - \sqrt{n}x = -\int_0^x \frac{(x-y) \, dy}{(1 + y/ \sqrt{n})^2}$$
This gives a uniform upper bound
$$ n \log\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right) - \sqrt{n} x \leq -cx^2$$
for some $c>0$, when $|x| \leq \sqrt{n}$ and
$$n \log\left(1 + \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right) - \sqrt{n} x \leq -c|x|\sqrt{n} $$
for $|x|> \sqrt{n}. \text{''}$.

I've been playing around with the first equation a bit, and I don't understand where the upper bounds come from.

How to tell at a glance (as Tao seems to) that these upper bounds hold?

Comment: The term inside the integral is less than x all the time, so x*(x-0)=x^2 ? Something like that?

Comment: Why are two cases given then?

Comment: Perhaps there should be a tilde on some x in the integral? Easy to make errors when the variable and the integration bounds have the same x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $|x|\leq \sqrt{n}$. First, consider the case $x>0$. Observe
\begin{align}
-\int^x_0 \frac{(x-y)\ dy}{(1+y/\sqrt{n})^2} \leq -\int^x_0 \frac{(x-y)}{4}\ dy = -\frac{1}{8}x^2
\end{align}
because
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \leq \left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \leq 2. 
\end{align}

In the case when $x<0$. Observe
\begin{align}
-\int^x_0 \frac{(x-y) dy}{(1+y/\sqrt{n})^2}= -\int^0_{-|x|} \frac{(|x|+y) dy}{(1+y/\sqrt{n})^2} \leq - \int^0_{-|x|} (|x|+y) dy = -\frac{x^2}{2}
\end{align}
since
\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac{y}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \leq 1.
\end{align}

Now, when $|x|> \sqrt{n}$. Consider the case $x>0$ and observe
\begin{align}
f(x):=n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{n} x \leq 0
\end{align}
because $f(\sqrt{n}) = n(\log 2- 3/4) \leq 0$ and $f'(x) \leq 0$ for all $x>\sqrt{n}$. Thus, it follows
\begin{align}
n\log\left( 1+ \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\sqrt{n} x< -\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{n}x.
\end{align}

Lastly, when $x<-\sqrt{n}$ we need to be cautious what Tao actually means because $\log(1-|x|/\sqrt{n})$ is not defined unless we look at the function $\log||x|/\sqrt{n}-1|$ instead.  But then the left-hand side will be positive. So...Tao probably made a typo.

Edit: He probably looked at the Taylor expansion to see that
\begin{align}
n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)= \sqrt{n} x - \frac{1}{2}x^2 + \frac{x^3}{3\sqrt{n}}-\ldots = \sqrt{n} x+ \mathcal{O}(x^2).
\end{align}
So when $x$ is small (in his case when $x/\sqrt{n}\leq 1$), it should follow that
\begin{align}
n\log\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\sqrt{n} x= \mathcal{O}(x^2).
\end{align}
However, Taylor expansion approximation doesn't really work when you are far away from where you want to expand. But when $x$ is big (in your case $x/\sqrt{n}>>1$), it should be clear that
\begin{align}
n\log\left(1+ \frac{x}{\sqrt{n}}\right)-\sqrt{n} x 
\end{align} 
is dominated by $-\sqrt{n}x$ because $n\log(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{n}})$ doesn't grow fast enough to overtake $-\sqrt{n}x$.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is helpful. Part of my question was asking for advice on how to "eyeball" this sort of inequality without checking all the cases. So if you have any remarks addressing that, they would be appreciated.